# How to set bottom margin in TCPDF?

Tags: tcpdf, html-to-pdf

I am using TCPDF for generating pdf. I am able to set margin for left,top and right using `SetMargins($left, $top, $right = -1, $keepmargins = false)` but not able to set margin for the bottom of the pdf page.

Can any one help me to set bottom margin in TCPDF? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

change the values of PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM in the following code (taken from TCPDF examples):

```php
// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
```