# TcPDF, How to add footer margin

Tags: php, pdf, margin, footer, tcpdf

This is TCPDF Image. I need to set a margin at the bottom. How can I set margin to break page after 57 row, then some space and footer and more content go to the next page?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [so]! We expect questions here to relate to _specific_ programming problems. Just telling what you need is likely to be considered as "too broad" or "unclear what you are asking". We expect everyone to do some own research first. Tell us what you've tried, and where you are stuck. See also: [ask]

Comment: `$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);` sets the footer margin, `$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);` also should be of use to you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set bottom margin in TCPDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45027747/how-to-set-bottom-margin-in-tcpdf)